# Rails has_many through association with inheritance issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If we have 3 models => Customer, User and Thing and another model Owner thats inherits from User and we try create a `has_many through` association like this:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :things, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :owners, through: :things
end

class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :customer, foreign_key: "customer_id"
 belongs_to :owner, foreign_key: "owner_id"
end

class Owner < User
 has_many :things, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :customers, through: :things
end
```

Why will `@owner.things` not work for us? (@owner is an instance of Owner). It gives `undefined method "things"` error.

@owner is the current_user, but how do you specify it to be an instance of User?

Is the only solution to change `owner_id` to `user_id` or is there a better solution, please?

Comment: What is the value of `@owner`?

Comment: Are you sure `@owner` is an instance of `Owner`?

Comment: Oops, yeah it is current_user

Comment: `current_user` may be a `User` class that is unaware of the `Owner` subclass.

Comment: Basically, @owner is the current_user, but how do you specify it to be instance of Owner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you state, `current_user` is an instance of `User`, not of its subclass, `Owner`.

If you want to add that relation to the `current_user`, you could add it to its class, `User`, instead of `Owner`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base # or whatever superclass you have for User
  has_many :things, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Otherwise, if you want to stick to `Owner`, you should overwrite the creation of `current_user` so that it uses the `Owner` class instead of `User`.

Comment: Okay, but it still demands to have user_id in the table Things?

Comment: Do I have to change owner_id to user_id in Things table? Is that the problem and only option to change?

Comment: It depends which approach you choose. If you only use `User` and get rid of `Owner`, of course you'll need `user_id`. If you add the `has_many :things` relation to `User`, you could set the inverse `belongs_to :user` in `Thing` and use the `user_id` column in `things`. `User has_many :things` expects a `user_id` column in the `things` table by default, unless stated otherwise.

Comment: I need to have Owner model, so I have to use it. So basically you are saying above I must use `user_id` in Things table in any case?

Comment: and there is no way to have owner_id in this association as I understand?

Comment: The main point is that you define a association in a subclass of the class you want to use the association for. You have to decide what instance you need `current_user` to be and define the associations accordingly. Based on this, you'll need to tweak your foreign keys if the defaults don't suit you.